# Shipping tab is empty when creating products in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, product, shipping, shipping-methods

I am a beginner in Magento, When I try to create a new product in Magento then the shipping tab is empty. I enabled shipping methods in store. This may be a simple question.

[image: Shipping tab is empty]

Answer (score 0):

The Shipping tab defines international and packaging data for products in your catalog. Data defined on this tab is used by Magento Shipping to pre-fill shipping information for customers during checkout and for other order fulfillment workflows.

Refer this link for more details :
https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/catalog/product-shipping.html

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I enable this ?

Comment: Enable FedEx or DHL maybe it work

Comment: I enabled both but not working.